# ncat web server how getting request parameters and client ip

Tags: linux, bash, server, netcat

i use ncat as web server for simple webpages written in bash. but how can i get the get and post request parameters and client ip from the current request? i tried it with redirecting the stdout and error pipes to log file. but this is buggy because i always get only the log from the previous request, not the current request.

here my code:
terminal command:

```
while true; do bash indexlog.sh | ncat -lv 8000 &>>ncat.log;done
cat indexlog.sh:
#!/bin/bash
echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
echo -e '<!DOCTYPE html>'
echo -e '<html lang="en">'
echo -e '<head>'
echo -e '<meta charset="utf-8"/>'
echo -e '</head>'
echo -e '<body>'
echo -e '<pre>'
echo request time=$(date)
cat ncat.log
echo ''>ncat.log
echo -e '</pre>'
echo -e '</body>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script runs and outputs to the pipe. Then the listening `ncat` process starts. Try running the listener as a separate process. Start the listener first.

```
# listener process: (`-k` to keepalive)
ncat -lk 8000 >> ncat.log
```

Then in another terminal for example:

```
# incoming requests
while true; do
   ./indexlog.sh | ncat localhost 8000
    sleep 5
done
```

**Edit**
Also remove these lines, which may work but could cause conflict as one processes has to re-seek to the start of the log due to truncation-:

```
cat ncat.log
echo ''>ncat.log
```

Comment: i tried your code, but firefox hangs with 'waiting for localhost...'
and also does it hang with curl.

Comment: and ncat twice with another terminal gets error that port already in use:ncat -lk 8000 >> ncat.log
Ncat: bind to :::8000: Address already in use. QUITTING.

Comment: There should be only one listener. Therefore use `ncat localhost 8000` for the client - do not use `-lk` flags for client.

Comment: that does not work too on my computer. did you try it on your pc and it works? but i found out one thing, how i cat get the remote ip, it is stores as an environment variable of ncat. while true; do ncat -lv 8000 -c 'echo $NCAT_REMOTE_ADDR and $NCAT_STDIN_FD';done now the only thing i still need too is the url query string, with the get params, or even better would be post params...i found out that this could work with ncat --lua-exec

Comment: lua would seem the best available method to parse http parameters.

Comment: lua doesnt help: terminal1: user1@pc1:~/ncattest$ ncat -klv 8000 --lua-exec hello.lua terminal2: user1@pc1:~$ cd ncattest/
user1@pc1:~/ncattest$ cat hello.lua 
#!/usr/bin/lua
print(os.getenv("QUERY_STRING"))
user1@pc1:~/ncattest$ curl localhost:8000/a
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
user1@pc1:~/ncattest$

Comment: oh wait...now there is coming something: user1@pc1:~/ncattest$ curl localhost:8000/a?b=3&c=5
[1] 20329
user1@pc1:~/ncattest$ curl: (52) Empty reply from server

[1]+  Exit 52                 curl localhost:8000/a?b=3
user1@pc1:~/ncattest$

Answer (score 0):

now with ncat+lua script comes something back. looks like an object reference or so:
terminal1:

```
user1@pc1:~/ncattest$ ncat -klv 8000 --lua-exec hello.lua
```

terminal2:

```
user1@pc1:~/ncattest$ cat hello.lua 
#!/usr/bin/lua
print(os.getenv("QUERY_STRING"))
user1@pc1:~/ncattest$ curl localhost:8000/a
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
user1@pc1:~/ncattest$ curl localhost:8000/?a=3&g=5
[1] 20312
user1@pc1:~/ncattest$ curl: (52) Empty reply from server

[1]+  Exit 52                 curl localhost:8000/?a=3
user1@pc1:~/ncattest$ curl localhost:8000/?a=3&g=5
[1] 20317
user1@pc1:~/ncattest$ curl: (52) Empty reply from server

[1]+  Exit 52                 curl localhost:8000/?a=3
user1@pc1:~/ncattest$ curl localhost:8000/a
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
user1@pc1:~/ncattest$ curl localhost:8000/a?b=3&c=5
[1] 20329
user1@pc1:~/ncattest$ curl: (52) Empty reply from server

[1]+  Exit 52                 curl localhost:8000/a?b=3
user1@pc1:~/ncattest$
```

but this does not help. the problem is still, that there is no query_string environment variable in pure ncat environment. and so there is no useful dynamic webpages possible. so i need to stay with cgi scripting, if i want to go to real basically web scripting with bash...
so the only way at this ncat bash level to get the query string, with with the first try of redirecting the stdout and stderr of bash. but this doesnt work for me.